# Getting error in console for iPad application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

I am getting an error while I tried to push ViewController in table's didSelectRow in iPad app.

**Error which I get is:**

`** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',`      `reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle /Users/abc/Library/Application` ``` Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/CFC7803E-4E44-45BF-9F47-``E24DDB44F286/SampleIpad.app> (loaded)' with name 'DetailView'' ```

Code in table's `didSelectRow` method :

```
DetailView *detailViewController = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];

// ...
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

What can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, Right click the viewController .m file in Xcode

- Click GetInfo
- Go to Targets tab and check if the checkbox next to your target project is checked? If not, do check that checkbox.
- Clean and Rebuild your code.

This would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the missing nib file.Check whether your application folder on the disk contains the DetailView.xib file. If it is present you may try using `[NSBundle mainBundle]` instead of nil in the bundle parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It is there in folder, and I also tried `[NSBundle nainBundle]`.

Comment: @Meghan Is the DetailView.xib part of the project too and not just on disk? When you select it and do get info is it selected as part of the target?

Comment: It was target problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[NSBundle mainBundle];
```